# Dictionary with multiple values to tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary with multiple values follows:

```
dict_a = {1: {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3},  2:{'a': 4, 'b':5, c:'6'}}
```

.
I want the result as such:

```
[('a',(1,4)),('b',(2,5)), ('c',(3,6))]
```

I wrote a code:

```
for keys, values in dict_a:  
    for k, v in values:  
        print(v)
```

But the result comes like `('a',1),('b',2)`....
I am little stuck here. Can anyone help me on this please!!!

Comment: Print isn't used for manipulating data.

Comment: What if a character (like `a`) appears only once or appears more than twice? Do you want the tuple that follows the character in your desired result to change in length? Also, is the result really supposed to be a list of tuples or is it to be another dictionary? If a list, does the order of the items in the list matter?

Comment: I was just checking the outputs here @Deniziloe.

Comment: You want to reshape your dictionary and group the keys in the dictionaries that are contained in the values?

Comment: yup, I have predefined keys in a nested dictionary... so, a,b,c will always be a,b,c. But I need to compare and extract values with particular keys from another dictionary. So, I was looking forward to group keys such that I can directly obtain values by comparing the keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
dict_a = {1: {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, 2: {'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6}}

res = [(k, tuple(d[k] for d in dict_a.values())) for k in dict_a[1]]

[('a', (1, 4)), ('b', (2, 5)), ('c', (3, 6))]
```

Assumes:

1. `dict_a` is ordered by outer key, which may be automatic in Python 3.6+. Otherwise, use `collections.OrderedDict`.
2. The keys in each dictionary value of `dict_a` are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `collections.defaultdict`:

***Setup***

```
from collections import defaultdict    
dct = defaultdict(tuple)
```

---

```
for _, v in dict_a.items():
    for el in v:
        dct[el] += (v[el],)

print(list(dct.items())
```

```
[('a', (1, 4)), ('b', (2, 5)), ('c', (3, '6'))]
```